# Nested @OneToOne -> @OneToMany not populating @OneToMany child object

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, one-to-many, one-to-one

**Problem Summary:**

I have three @entities with the following relationship:
CustomerOrder -> @OneToOne -> Reservation -> @OneToMany -> ProductOrder.

When I call the controller to fetch CustomerOrder directly, CustomerOrder and the Reservation child object is pulled. The `List<ProductOrder>` remains empty.

If I call the controller to fetch Reservation directly, then the `List<ProductOrder>` under Reservation is fully populated.

When I print out the SQL that Hibernate generates to fetch `List<ProductOrder>`, that SQL does in fact pull the appropriate ProductOrder list but spring is not populating the list.

**Details:**

I have three classes (Getters and setters omitted for brevity):

**CustomerOrder:**

```
@Entity
public class CustomerOrder {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(
        name="id",referencedColumnName="customerOrderId",insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Reservation reservation;

}
```

**Reservation**

```
@Entity
public class Reservation {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

//Tie a reservation back to a customer order
private Long customerOrderId;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "reservationId", 
    referencedColumnName="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private List<ProductOrder> productOrderList = new ArrayList<ProductOrder>();
```

}

**Product Order:**

```
@Entity
public class ProductOrder {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private Long customerOrderId;

private Long reservationId;

}
```

I also have two endpoints. One that can fetch a reservation directly, or one that can fetch a reservation via a customerOrder:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer-order/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody CustomerOrder findOne(@PathVariable(value="id") Long id) {     

    return CustomerOrder customerOrder = customerOrderRepository.findOne(id);

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/reservation/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Reservation findOne(@PathVariable(value="id") Long id) {       

    return reservationService.findOne(id);

}
```

**I am using spring-boot version 1.3.5.RELEASE with MySQL 5.6.23**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what is going on.

Initially I had Reservation have a @OneToMany relationship with CustomerOrder. This meant that my mapping should used like this:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(
        name="customerOrderId",referencedColumnName="id",insertable=false, updatable=false)
private List<Reservation> reservation;
```

I then changed my code to use a @OneToOne mapping. When I did this I flipped my join column to look like this:
`@JoinColumn(name="id",referencedColumnName="customerOrderId",insertable=false, updatable=false)`

This action is wrong. When I was getting a reservation object via the CustomerOrder object through a mapping, it was actually getting the **wrong** reservation object because of an incorrect @JoinColumn mapping.

The correct solution is to modify my CustomerOrder @entity to have an ID which references Reservation.

My CustomerOrder class now looks like this:

```
private Long reservationId;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(
        name="reservationId",referencedColumnName="id",insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Reservation reservation;
```

Woops.